# C# XNA generate MIDI

Tags: c#, xna, midi, procedural-generation, procedural-music

I wish to play MIDI like notes from the C# XNA program. I don't actually need to construct a MIDI file, just have the ability to start and stop notes or play them for a given time.

```
play("flute", "D4", "start");
play("flute", "D4", "stop");
play("flute", "E4", "5 secs");
```

Comment: I'm asking how to do this MyKuLLSKI, not giving a solution, of course the code above won't work, most noticed this immediately.

Comment: I don't think you understand my comment. I said pseudo code. Google that and you'll understand

Comment: I know what pseudo code is. I know play("flute", "D4", "start"); won't play the note. It's not "bad pseudo code", it's just an example. There's nothing to try, Google revealed nothing useful with the searches I tried.

Comment: I take it you have no idea what my first comment said. I'm simply saying STOP writing pseudo code and write real code. People will be more likely to help if you at least tried something!

Comment: How could I have written real code? If I could have written real code I wouldn't need to ask how to write code for this task.

Comment: It wasn't easily found on Google or I wouldn't have asked it. It may have been if you knew how to word the search, because you knew what to look for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend looking at the [XNA Midi Project](http://thexnamidiproject.codeplex.com/).

It includes two examples and is easy to use:

```
NoteOn(int channel, int note, int velocity, int program)
```

Unlike other solutions like using WinAPI this will also run on XBox and WP7.

Comment: and FM stuff too, tyvm, looks interesting. I'm breaking down the example right now to understand it.